# Curious redirection problem using location.href

Tags: javascript, redirect

I face a curious problem with redirection...

Look at this small example: it works only if I add the alert() call after the redirection sentence!  If I remove the alert() it does not work anymore!!!

Any idea why (I'm using Firefox 3)?

Thanks.

```
<html>



<script type="text/javascript">

function GotoPage() { 

    location.href = "http://www.yahoo.com";

    // Without this alert redirection does not work!!! 

    alert("Hello!"); 

}

</script>



<body>

    <form>

    <button onclick="javascript:GotoPage()">Go</button>

    </form>

</body>



</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure, but I suppose that, if you don't return `false` in your `onclick` handler, the default action of the button is executed -- and that is not redirecting.

The alert freezes the browser long enough so the redirection is made before the control is given back to the default behavior of the button element.

Try using something like this :

```
<button onclick="GotoPage(); return false;">Go</button>
```

Or try modifying the function so it returns `false` :

```
function GotoPage() { 
    location.href = "http://www.yahoo.com";
    return false;
}
```

And return,in your onclick handler, what the function returned :

```
<button onclick="return GotoPage();">Go</button>
```

BTW : no need for the `javascript:` part.

Comment: Pascal,

Many thanks! The first option solved the problem (the others don't)!!

But I'm still curious about why adding the alert() call makes it work???

Anyway, thanks again!

Best regards,

Comment: You're welcome :-) ;;; the alert is preventing the browser from executing the default action of the button element *(at it prevents the function from ending, returning control to its caller)*. location.href, on the other hand, is assigned before the alert, so it's being executed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should set window.location, not location.href.

```
function GotoPage() {
    window.location = "http://www.yahoo.com";
}
```

Comment: Actually neither. You should specify both that the location object is in the window object (to elliminiate naming conflicts) and that it's the href property that you want to set (as some browsers won't work with assigning the URL to the location object directly). So you should use `window.location.href`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use window.location.assign instead of window.location.href

Once, I used the function like yours without the alert statement, and when I tried it on FireFox, it wouldn't work. After that, I used function assign() instead of assigning the href property and it worked well for me.